# Value of a vector in Haskell

Tags: math, haskell

I'm trying to learn Haskell from Learn You a Haskell for Great Good. I'm trying to build a bunch of functions to perform various vector operations. I'm building a function that takes two vectors, and finds the angle in between them. The operation looks like this: 
A · B = A B cos θ

Anyway, right now I'm trying to write a function that will find "Value" of a Vector. For example, the value of 2i + 3j + 4k is sqrt(2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2).

The vector is stored as a list, and I was thinking of trying something like this:

```
getValue (vector) = [sqrt v | v <- v + square take 1 vector]
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual name for this is "norm", or more precisely "Euclidean norm". You sum up the squares of the components and calculate the square root of the sum. With the vectors represented as lists of components, it becomes

```
-- assuming the component type is Double
norm :: Vector -> Double
norm vector = sqrt $ sum [x*x | x <- vector]
```

or, with `map` instead of the list comprehension,

```
norm vector = sqrt . sum $ map (\x -> x*x) vector
```

If you like point-free style, you can also write the latter as

```
norm :: Vector -> Double
norm = sqrt . sum . map (\x -> x*x)
```

Comment: To be really point-free, you can replace `\x -> x*x` with `(^2)`, to get `sqrt . sum . map (^2)`.  (Or `join (*)` if you feel like being needlessly monadic.)

Comment: @AntalS-Z With GHC >= 7.4, yes, `(^2)` is okay. Then `(^2)` has a rewrite rule that gives you `\x -> x*x`. With GHC <= 7.2, you really get `(^2)`, and you don't want that (way slower). `join (*)` works also with older GHCs, but I didn't think bringing in the Monad instance for `(->) a` would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

First define scalar multiplication, which is useful in its own right. I used `|*|` as operator:

```
(|*|) = (sum .) . zipWith (*)
```

Then the rest is trivial:

```
norm v = sqrt $ v |*| v
```

Comment: This is incorrect: the applicative instance for lists treats them as nondeterminism, and so `[2,3,4] |*| [2,3,4] = sum [2*2,2*3,2*4,3*2,3*3,3*4,4*2,4*3,4*4]`.  You want `ZipList`s there: `a |*| b = sum . getZipList $ liftA2 (*) (ZipList a) (ZipList b)`.

Comment: An easy mistake to make.  (Also, `zipWith` is a much better choice than `ZipList`s.  What was I thinking?)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are representing your vectors as a list then:

```
getValue :: (Floating a) => [a] -> a
getValue = sqrt . sum . map (\i -> i * i)
```

Alternatively you can use a list comprehension to do the squaring of values:

```
getValue :: (Floating a) => [a] -> a
getValue vector = sqrt . sum $ [x * x | x <- vector]
```